# Exporting an Azure Machine Learning Experiment to a Jupyter notebook

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm new to machine learning and I created an experiment in Azure Machine Learning Studio.
[image: experiement]

Is there a way to export this code to python or a jupyter notebook? I have not been able to find anything in Microsoft's documentation

Answer (score 1):

Not currently but it is a goal! In the meantime you I encourage you to try out the SDK